# MediaPlayer.setDataSource deprecated on android 6

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I am creating an app using MediaPlayer to play audio file from raw folder. It works fine on android 7 and above but for android 6 it crashes. It seems MediaPlayer.setDataSource is deprecated on android 6. So what should be used to make MediaPlayer work on android 6. Is there any alternate that i can use just for making my app work on android 6.

I downloaded and tried running the sample app from developer.android.com but it also crashes on android 6.

Crash Logs -

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setDataSource(Landroid/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor;)V in class Landroid/media/MediaPlayer; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.media.MediaPlayer' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
        at com.example.android.mediaplayersample.MediaPlayerHolder.loadMedia(MediaPlayerHolder.java:86)
        at com.example.android.mediaplayersample.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
```

Comment: do yourself a favour and use ExoPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems MediaPlayer.setDataSource is deprecated on android 6

No, [the method that you are trying to call](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer?hl=en#setDataSource(android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor)) did not exist then. It was added in API Level 24.

> So what should be used to make MediaPlayer work on android 6

For a raw resource, use [the static `create()` method that takes a resource ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int)).